# How we can get that at a particular place marker is present or not

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am making dynamic markers. I got success in that. But here is problem that if there is two same lat-log then it place only one marker there.
Instead of that I want to change the marker icon if there is two same lat-log.
I am taking lat-log from database.
Any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have found the solution of this problem.
I am using two array
The code is as following:

```
var contentStrings = new Array();
var markers = new Array();
```

and getting the position

```
var pos = marker.getPosition();
                var isPresent = false;
                var index;
                for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    if(String(pos) == String(markers[i])) {
                        isPresent = true;
                        index = i;
                    }
                }
                if(isPresent) { 
                    contentString = contentStrings[index] + '<div><br/> Tutor Name : '+data.name+'<br/>Link : '+data.url+'</div>';
                } else {
                    markers.push(pos);
                    contentString = '<div> Tutor Name : '+data.name+'<br/>Link : '+data.url+'</div>';
                    contentStrings.push(contentString);
                }
```

Its really working fine.